# Cookie through a form and GET

Tags: php, mysql, get

I am using the $_GET function to carry a database field forward throughout a form. However i have come across a stumbling block when i try to pull the information from the database:

```
<?php
$prodname=$_GET["q"];
?>

 <h3>Product Name: <u><?php echo $prodname; ?></u></h3><br />
  <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","cl49-vogalcms","vogalcms");
if (!$con) 
  {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

  $prodname=$row['prodname'];
 $catagory=$row['catagory'];

@mysql_select_db("cl49-XXX",$con)or die('Unable to select database ln 60:'.mysql_error());
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE prodname=$prodname")or die('ln 61 :'.mysql_error());
$cnt=$_COOKIE["count"];


setcookie("user",$myid,time()+10000);
mysql_close($con);
?>

  <form name="newad" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="drtsavepic.php?q=<?php echo"$prodname"; ?>">  <br> <Br>
   <input type="file" name="image">
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Upload image">

  </form>
```

When i run this code, i get the following error

> ln 61 :You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

Can anyone shine any light on this issue?

Comment: I hope you have mysql_real_escape_string arround your vars?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQLinjection and you are using deprecated functions. Use mysqli http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php or pdo http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php.

Comment: @TobSpr - Not sure what that means - Php Novie here!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_real_escape_string.asp "Use this function to prevent database attack!"

Answer (score 4):

try replacing this  `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE prodname=$prodname")`

by

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE prodname='".$prodname."'")
```

Comment: Thanks done this which got rid of the error! However, if i then put an echo statement under this `echo" the name of this product is $prodname";`The page just shows 'The name of this product is'  How do i get the prodname to show?

Comment: hmmmm...$prodname=$row['prodname'];...Where is $row in your code?

Comment: Hmm - PHP novice here - Not sure??

Comment: I guess it is empty. Hence you are getting an empty result. Please check for $row

Comment: where would `$prodname=$row['prodname'];` go?

Comment: Look after if (!$con) 
  {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }....you have written  $prodname=$row['prodname'];

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your productname variable in quotes,

like this

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE prodname='$prodname'")or die('ln 61 :'.mysql_error());
```

Because there might be case when your product name be two words with a space, where query fails

Comment: Thanks @chandresh_cool thats got rid of the error! However, if i then put an echo statment under this `echo" the name of this product is $prodname";`The page just shows "The name of this product is"?

Comment: That means your productname variable i.e $prodname is empty or say null.